# Replacing [[Words]] with other [[Words]] from a reference file in Notepad++ using Javascript

Tags: python, regex, replace, notepad++, regexp-replace

I have a translation file that looks like this:

```
Apple=Apfel
Apple pie=Apfelkuchen
Banana=Banane
Bananaisland=Bananen Insel
Cherry=Kirsche
Train=Zug
```

...500+ more lines like that

now I have a file I need to work on with text. Only certain parts of text needs to be replaced, example:

```
The [[Apple]] was next to the [[Banana]]. Meanwhile the [[Cherry]] was chilling by the [[Train]]. 
The [[Apple pie]] tastes great on the [[Bananaisland]].
```

Result needs to be

```
The [[Apfel]] was next to the [[Banane]]. Meanwhile the [[Kirsche]] was chilling by the [[Zug]].
The [[Apfelkuchen]] tastes great on the [[Bananen Insel]].
```

There are way too many incident to copy/paste manually. What is an easy way to search for [[XXX]] and replace from another file as mentioned?

I tried getting help for this for many hours but to no avail. The closest I have gotten was this script:

```
import re
separators = "=", "\n"

def custom_split(sepr_list, str_to_split):
    # create regular expression dynamically
    regular_exp = '|'.join(map(re.escape, sepr_list))
    return re.split(regular_exp, str_to_split)

with open('D:/_working/paired-search-replace.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        s = custom_split(separators, l)
        editor.replace(s[0], s[1])
```

However, this will replace too much, or not consistent. E.g. [[Apple]] gets correctly replaced by [[Apfel]] but [[File:Apple.png]] gets wrongly replaced by [[File:Apfel.png]] and [[Apple pie]] gets replaced by [[Apfel pie]], so I tried tweaking the regular expression for hours on end to no avail. Does anyone have any info -in very simple terms please- how I can fix this/achieve my goal?

Comment: Also posted on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/1638588/214658) twice using code parts from answer there. Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little tricky because [ is a meta character in regex.

I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do it but this works:

```py
replaces="""Apple=Apfel
Apple pie=Apfelkuchen
Banana=Banane
Bananaisland=Bananen Insel
Cherry=Kirsche
Train=Zug"""


text = """
The [[Apple]] was next to the [[Banana]]. Meanwhile the [[Cherry]] was chilling by the [[Train]]. 
The [[Apple pie]] tastes great on the [[Bananaisland]].
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import re
    for replace in replaces.split('\n'):
        english, german = replace.split('=')
        text = re.sub(rf'\[\[{english}\]\]', f'[[{german}]]', text)

    print(text)
```

outputs:

```
The [[Apfel]] was next to the [[Banane]]. Meanwhile the [[Kirsche]] was chilling by the [[Zug]]. 
The [[Apfelkuchen]] tastes great on the [[Bananen Insel]].
```

Answer (score 0):

First, read in the file with translations:

```py
translations={}
with open('file/with/translations.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        items = line.strip().split('=', 1)
        translations[items[0]] = items[1]
```

I assume the phrases/words are unique in the file.
Then, you need to match all substrings between `[[` and `]]`, capture the text in between (with a regex like `\[\[(.*?)]]`, see [the online demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZGNYdz/1)), check if there is a key with the group 1 value in the `translations` dictionary, and replace with `[[` + dictionary value + `]]` if there is such a key, or return the whole match if there is no such a translation:

```py
text = """The [[Apple]] was next to the [[Banana]]. Meanwhile the [[Cherry]] was chilling by the [[Train]]. 
The [[Apple pie]] tastes great on the [[Bananaisland]]."""

import re
translated_text = re.sub(r"\[\[(.*?)]]", lambda x: f'[[{translations[x.group(1)]}]]' if x.group(1) in translations else x.group(), text)
```

Output:

```py
>>> translated_text
'The [[Apfel]] was next to the [[Banane]]. Meanwhile the [[Kirsche]] was chilling by the [[Zug]]. \nThe [[Apfelkuchen]] tastes great on the [[Bananen Insel]].'
```